How to dynamically filter properties by Jackson
Let's assume there is a class like the following:
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private boolean nameSpecified;

    private LocalDateTime birthday;
    private boolean birthdaySpecified;

    private String jobTitle;
    private boolean jobTitleSpecified;

    public String getName() {
        if (!nameSpecified) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The property `name` is not specified");
        }
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nameSpecified = true;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getBirthday() {
        if (! birthdaySpecified) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The property `birthday` is not specified");
        }
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(LocalDateTime name) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.birthdaySpecified = true;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        if (!jobTitleSpecified) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The property `jobTitle` is not specified");
        }
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.jobTitleSpecified = true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Employee");
        String separator = " {";
        if (nameSpecified) {
            builder.append(separator).append("name=").append(name);
            separator = ", ";
        }
        if (birthdaySpecified) {
            builder.append(separator).append("birthday=").append(birthday);
            separator = ", ";
        }
        if (jobTitleSpecified) {
            builder.append(separator).append("jobTitle=").append(jobTitle);
        }
        return builder.append("}").toString();
    }
}

It's obvious that the Employee object is NOT POJO, some properties are not specified or set to null are totally different.

This is popular design in ORM

Unspecified: The value of the property is unknown
Null: The value property is known, it has no data.

For example, since hibernate3, it is used by lazy scalar properties.

This is actually a way to make objects dynamic while retaining the advantages of strongly-typed language.
Clearly, the default Jackson cannot serialize/deserialize this object, and Jackson's behavior needs to be overridden, unspecified properties must be skipped (like the logic of toString).
Properties that are not specified need to be ignored by Jackson, which is highly similar to the requirement of @JsonFilter, with the only difference being that the filtering rules are not fixed but independent for each object.
I tried to solve this problem by registering custom Serializer and Deserializer through a custom Jackson Module. However, my custom read/write strategies are not as comprehensive as the standard Jackson behaviors, and inevitably break some advanced Jackson features such as @JsonAlias, @JsonView, inheritance, and polymorphism.
Therefore, I need to implement dynamic object filtering without breaking any advanced Jackson features, as if each object had its own @JsonFilter.
Is there an elegant way to achieve my requirement?

Actually, the class mentioned above is a logical equivalent extracted from my own framework, which is very simple and suitable for discussion as a standalone problem. In my framework, to handle such dynamic objects, I custom-defined ImmutableSerializer and ImmutableDeserializer to handle Jackson serialization/deserialization of dynamic objects. However, my approach cannot accommodate all advanced Jackson features, and users have reported bugs related to certain advanced Jackson features being broken over the past two years, which has been bothering me a lot.

Just for clarification - "some properties are not specified or set to null are totally different". From your code, I take this to mean such properties can either be (a) not specified (using the boolean false); or (b) specified with a value, including a null value. So, somewhat similar to the "what does null mean?" question. But how does that relate to the term "dynamic object"? Not dynamic typing...? maybe some other meaning?

Unspecified: Data is unknown.
Specified: Data is known, it is null.
This is popular design in ORM, in Hibernate3+, it is used for lazy scalar properties

This is still a little bit confusing for me. Either the property is not set meaning it never had a value (the data is unknown would implicitly mean that it could have data, but you just don't know) or the property is set but explicitly set empty (meaning null). What do you want to achieve? Is it that you only want to serialize a property if it was set (meaning the serialized json won't contain the property at all)?

The design appears bad; specifically jobTitleSpecified, birthdaySpecified, and jobTitleSpecified provide no value.  Just use jobTitle == null to indicate that it is not present (i.e. there is no job title value).  Not specified is the same as "specified and has no value".

Just a simple example, actually

If property is primitive, a boolean flag is required.
If property is nullable class type, a boolean flag is required.
If property is non-null class type,  a boolean flag is not required because null mean unspecified.

For the sake of simplicity, I didn't say whether the property itself is allowed to be null or not, and always used the boolean flag.
This feature was first introduced in Hibernate 3 and is used to express unknown scalar properties (e.g. large fields), rather than unknown associations that existed in Hibernate2.

Of course, Hibernate can choose a bytecode enhancement at compile time to modify the implementation logic of the pojo. I'm just writing this logic enhancement in pseudocode here.
@DwB
This design has existed in this world for a long time but is called bad design because you don't know it. It's so ridiculous

If i get your question right you could do something like this:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SerializerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create an instance of MyEntity with name and age
        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity("John Doe", 30);

        // Create a customized ObjectMapper for serialization
        ObjectMapper mapper = createObjectMapper();

        // Serialize the entity to JSON and print the output
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(entity);
        System.out.println(json);
    }

    public static ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        // Instantiate a new ObjectMapper
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Configure the mapper to ignore empty properties for serialization
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);

        // Register a module to customize serialization for Property class
        mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule() {
            @Override
            public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
                super.setupModule(context);
                
                // Register a serializer modifier to handle instances of Property class
                context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new BeanSerializerModifier() {
                    @Override
                    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(
                            SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription desc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
                        // If the property being serialized is of type Property, use the custom PropertySerializer
                        if (Property.class.isAssignableFrom(desc.getBeanClass())) {
                            return new PropertySerializer((JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer);
                        }
                        // Otherwise, use the default serializer
                        return serializer;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return mapper;
    }
}

// Represents an entity with name and age properties, using the Property wrapper
class MyEntity {
    private final Property<String> name;
    private final Property<Integer> age;

    // Constructor initializing name and age with the Property wrapper
    public MyEntity(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = new Property<>(name);
        this.age = new Property<>(age);
    }

    // Getters for name and age properties
    public Property<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Property<Integer> getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}

// A generic wrapper class for entity properties, tracking if a value has been explicitly set
class Property<T> {
    private T value; // The actual value of the property
    private boolean isSet = false; // Flag to track if the value has been explicitly set

    // Constructor that initializes the property value and marks it as set
    public Property(T value) {
        setValue(value); // Using setValue ensures isSet is correctly updated
    }

    // Getter for the property value
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // Setter for the property value, also marks the property as set
    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.isSet = true;
    }

    // Checks if the property has been explicitly set
    public boolean isSet() {
        return isSet;
    }
}

// Custom JsonSerializer for the Property class to handle serialization based on the isSet flag
class PropertySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Property<?>> {
    private final JsonSerializer<Object> defaultSerializer; // The default serializer for the actual value of the property

    // Constructor receiving the default serializer to be used for the property's value
    public PropertySerializer(JsonSerializer<Object> serializer) {
        defaultSerializer = serializer;
    }

    // Custom serialization logic that only serializes the property if it has been explicitly set
    @Override
    public void serialize(Property<?> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if(!value.isSet()) {
            return; // Skip serialization if the property has not been set
        }

        // Use the default serializer to serialize the value of the property
        defaultSerializer.serialize(value.getValue(), gen, provider);
    }

    // Determines if a Property is considered empty (not set), used to decide if a property should be omitted
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty(SerializerProvider provider, Property<?> value) {
        return !value.isSet();
    }
}

References:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria


Thanks, but I cannot do this. The is not a business project but a framework, ultimate performance is also a goal of this framework(you can view its benchmark), sot converting before serialization is not acceptable.
However, this last link looks very useful, great.

I don’t understand what you mean, there’s no conversion before serialization here. It’s just a sample that shows how you can use a generic type as wrapper, and write a module for custom serialization. The wrapper is meant to be used in your model class instead of having two properties for each field

Oh, Sorry, I forget something, this problem is not caused by serialization(it has been resolved two year ago), this problem is caused by deserialization. please view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78257427/how-to-provide-brand-new-jackson-deserialization-for-object

Yeah if you serialize from two fields to one field you loose the needed information for deserialization or you would need to have a state which represents that a value was never set for this property. Like undefined but unfortunately you can't use undefined in JSON. Why don't you just serialize all the information, you could use the Property wrapper from my answer and serialize it as whole object instead of only serializing the wrapped value. then you can also easily serialize and deserialize without needing to write custom logic for jackson

Or, and I would not recommend that since it's a very bad approach, you have some kind of string literal which describes the state you want.

No, it is not bad. It's just alone code that doesn't explain the specific scenario or why it's being done. This really doesn't seem like the usual programming idea.
But if you combine it with the actual scenario, you will find that this incredible approach at first glance has far more effect than you think (if you are interested, you can refer to https://babyfish-ct.github.io/jimmer-doc/docs/overview/introduction), and some experienced developers among the users are crazy about it. One of them is willing to give a video later (I can't speak English well to record video, but he can).

I don't think you understand what I'm saying. I don't say your framework is bad. I said, I would consider it bad practice to use a string literal to mark a field as in your terms "unspecified". The problem with this is simply that even though your string literal is not a value in most cases mayber theres that one case where that literal is same as a "specified" value.
